# How to install mongoDB on windows?

Tags: windows, installation, mongodb

I am trying to test out mongoDB and see if it is anything for me. I downloaded the 32bit windows version, but have no idea on how to continue from now on.

I normally use the WAMP services for developing on my local computer. Can i run mongoDB on Wamp?

However, what's the best (easiest!) way to make it work on windows?

Thanks!

Comment: A post I wrote with some gotchas to consider: http://www.dllhell.net/index.php/2010/05/01/on-installing-mongodb-as-a-service-on-windows/

Comment: I want an installer that install mongodb and then autorun it in service

Comment: Read this article http://www.pronique.com/blog/installing-mongodb-on-windows-the-wamp-way it is really good

Comment: Great step by step tutorials on what you need: http://www.codearsenal.net/2015/10/how-to-install-and-run-mongodb-in-windows.html

Comment: official mongoDB instructions: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/

Comment: You should mark @ShivamSrivastava 's answer as the correct one.

Comment: Is there any offline installer is available for MongoDB

Answer (score 97, accepted):

It's not like WAMP. You need to start mongoDB database with a command after directory has been created C:/database_mongo

`mongod --dbpath=C:/database_mongo/`

you can then connect to mongodb using commands.

Comment: On a side note Windows XP support is discontinued from v2.2+  http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.2/#windows-xp-is-not-supported

Comment: a simple utube video for windows installation - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=msQ2F5XUgms

Comment: `mongod` is not found after installing

Comment: you might need to add it to your PATH in windows.

Comment: Easy to do steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37548118/2404470) too

Answer (score 251):

## Mongo Installation Process in Windows

Are you ready for the installation … and use …
Technically, it’s not an installation it’s just Downloading…

I.   **Download** the zip file http://www.mongodb.org/downloads

II.  **Extract** it and copy the files into your desired location.

III. **Start** the DB engine.

IV.  **Test** the installation and use it.

*That's it! So simple, right? Ok let’s start*

---

### 1. Download the zip file

1. Go to http://www.mongodb.org/downloads
2. You will see a screen like this:
   [image: The mongo download page]
   I am using a windows 7 32 bit machine - that’s why I downloaded the package marked in red.
3. Click download (It only takes a few seconds).
   Wow... I got that downloaded. It was a zipped file called `mongodb-win32-i386-2.4.4.zip` (The name of the folder will change according to the version you download, here I got version 2.4.4).

*OK all set.*

---

### 2. Extract

1. Extract the zip
2. Copy the files into a desired location in your machine.

   - I am going to copy the extracted files to my D drive, since I don’t have many files there.
   - Alright then where are you planning to paste the mongo files? In C: or in your Desktop itself?
   - Ok, no matter where you paste... In the snap shot below, you can see that I have navigated to the bin folder inside the Mongo folder. I count fifteen files inside bin. What about you?

[image: The path to the bin folder]

*Finished! That’s all*

*What we have to do next?*

---

### 3. Start the DB engine

*Let’s go and start using our mongo db...*

1. Open up a command prompt, then navigate to `bin` in the mongo folder
   [image: Navigating to mongo's bin folder]
2. Type `mongo.exe` (which is the command used to start mongo Db Power shell). Then see the below response..
   [image: Executing mongo.exe]
   *That was an awesome exception J LOL … What is that?*

   > Couldn’t connect to server.

   *Why did the exception happen? I have no idea... Did I create a server in between?*

   *No.*

   *Right, then how come it connected to a server in between? Silly Machine …Jz.*

   *I got it! Like all other DBs - we have to start the DB engine before we use it.*

   *So, how can we start it?*
3. We have to start the mongo db by using the command `mongod`. Execute this from the `bin` folder of mongo.

   *Let’s see what had happened.*

   [image: error message]

   *Again a wonderfully formatted exception J we got right? Did you notice what I have highlighted on top? Yeah it is the mongod command. The second one is the exception asking us to create a folder called data. And, inside the data folder, a folder called `db`.*

   *So we have to create these `data\db` folders.*

   *The next question is where to create these folders?*
4. We have to create the `data\db` folders in the `C` drive of our BOX in which we are installing mongo. Let’s go and create the folder structure in C drive.

   A question arises here: "Is it mandatory to create the data\db directories inside C?" Nooo, not really. Mongo looks in `C` by default for this folder, but you can create them wherever you want. However, if it's not in `C`, you have to tell mongo where it is.

   *In other words, if you don't want the mongo databases to be on `C:\`, you have to set the db path for mongo.exe.*

   #### Optional

   - Ok, I will create those folders in some other location besides `C` for better understanding of this option. I will create then in the `D` drive root, with the help of cmd.

     Why? Because it’s an opportunity for us to remember the old dos commands...

     [image: md data]
   - The next step is to set the Db path to mongo.exe.

     Navigate back to `bin`, and enter the command, `mongod.exe --dbpath d:\data`.

     I got the response below:

     [image: --dbpath]

     I Hope everything went well... Because I didn’t see any ERROR *** in the console J.

   Next, we can go and start the db using the command `start mongo.exe`

   [image: start mongo.exe]

   I didn't see any error or warning messages. But, we have to supply a command to make sure mongo is up and running, i.e. mongod will get a response:

   [image: mongodb response]

Hope everything went well.

---

### 4. Test the Mongo DB installation

*Now we have to see our DB right? Yea very much, Otherwise how will we know it’s running?*

For testing purpose MONGO has got a DB called `test` by default. Lets go query that.

But how without any management studios? Unlike SQL, we have to depend on the command prompt. Yes exactly the same command prompt… our good old command prompt… Heiiiii..  Don’t get afraid yes it’s our old command prompt only.
Ok let’s go and see how we are going to use it…

Ohhh Nooo… **don’t close** the above Command prompt, leave it as it is…

1. Open a new cmd window.
2. Navigate to Bin as usual we do…

   I am sure you people may be remembering the old C programming which we have done on our college day’s right?
3. In the command prompt, execute the command `mongo` or `mongo.exe` again and see what happens.

   You will get a screen as shown below:

   [image: startup warning]
4. I mentioned before that Mongo has got a test db by default called `test`, try inserting a record into it.

   The next question here is "How will we insert?" Does mongo have SQL commands? No, mongo has got only commands to help with.

   > The basic command to **insert** is
   > db.test.save( { KodothTestField: ‘My name is Kodoth’ } )

   Where `test` is the DB and `.save` is the insert command. `KodothTestField` is the column or field name, and `My name is Kodoth` is the value.
5. Before talking more let’s check whether it’s stored or not by performing another command: `db.test.find()`

   [image: Mongo command to search for a document, similar to SELECT in SQL.]

   Our Data got successfully inserted … Hurrayyyyyy..

   I know that you are thinking about the number which is displayed with every record right called ObjectId. It’s like a unique id field in SQL that auto-increments and all. Have a closer look you can see that the Object Id ends with 92, so it’s different for each and every record.

   At last we are successful in installing and verifying the MONGO right. Let’s have a party...
   So do you agree now MONGO is as Sweet as MANGO?

Also we have 3rd party tools to explore the MONGO. One is called MONGO VUE. Using this tool we can perform operations against the mongo DB like we use Management studio for SQL Server.

Can you just imagine an SQL server or Oracle Db with entirely different rows in same table? Is it possible in our relational DB table? This is how mongo works. I will show you how we can do that…

---

First I will show you how the data will look in a relational DB.

For example consider an Employee table and a Student table in relational way. The schemas would be entirely different right? Yes exactly…

[image: results view]

Let us now see how it will look in Mongo DB. The above two tables are combined into single Collection in Mongo…

[image: MongoVUE]

This is how Collections are stored in Mongo. I think now you can feel the difference really right?
Every thing came under a single umbrella. This is not the right way but I just wanted to show you all how this happens that’s why I combined 2 entirely different tables in to one single Collection.

If you want to try out you can use below test scripts

```
*********************** 
TEST INSERT SCRIPT

*********EMPLOYEE****** 
db.test.save( { EmployeId: "1", EmployeFirstName: "Kodoth", EmployeLastName:"KodothLast", EmployeAge:"14" } )  
db.test.save( { EmployeId: "2", EmployeFirstName: "Kodoth 2", EmployeLastName:"Kodoth Last2", EmployeAge:"14" } )  
db.test.save( { EmployeId: "3", EmployeFirstName: "Kodoth 3", EmployeLastName:"Kodoth Last3", EmployeAge:"14" } ) 

******STUDENT****** 
db.test.save( { StudentId: "1", StudentName: "StudentName", StudentMark:"25" } )  
db.test.save( { StudentId: "2", StudentName: "StudentName 2", StudentMark:"26" } )  
db.test.save( {StudentId: "3", StudentName: "StudentName 3", StudentMark:"27"} )
************************
```

Thanks

Comment: Suggestion to the mongodb team: create this default data directory for us upon installation.

Comment: If anybody gets  `Cannot start server. The default storage engine 'wiredTiger' is not available` Try this : `mongod --storageEngine=mmapv1 --dbpath [your-path]`

Comment: Awesome!! This was the best answer I could find! I was hung up after starting mongod - you need to open another shell and type mongo.exe

Comment: Thanks, this should probably be used as a standard "model" for Stack overflow answers :-) , well documented.

Comment: Just wanted to add, for anyone using Windows and running into an 'illegal character' syntax error, that when adding data in the shell you should use double quotes e.g.:

db.test.save({"Cool":"This Works"})

Comment: This is a good answer.  I think relation-ally, so I am going to have to get familiar with schemas and the like before I feel "safe" with a NoSQL DB.

Comment: I wanted to upvote this answer but couldn't due to the unnecessary dialogue and incomplete or "buggy"(?) markup.

Answer (score 63):

Pretty good documentation is provided on the [MongoDB website](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Quickstart+Windows)

> ### Install MongoDB
>
> 1. #### Determine which MongoDB build you need.
>
>    There are three builds of MongoDB for Windows:
>
>    MongoDB for Windows Server 2008 R2 edition (i.e. 2008R2) runs only on Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows 7 64-bit, and newer versions of
>      Windows. This build takes advantage of recent enhancements to the
>      Windows Platform and cannot operate on older versions of Windows.
>
>    MongoDB for Windows 64-bit runs on any 64-bit version of Windows newer than Windows XP, including Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows 7
>      64-bit.
>
>    MongoDB for Windows 32-bit runs on any 32-bit version of Windows newer than Windows XP. 32-bit versions of MongoDB are only intended
>      for older systems and for use in testing and development systems.
>      32-bit versions of MongoDB only support databases smaller than 2GB.
>
>    To find which version of Windows you are running, enter the following command in the Command Prompt:
>
>    ```batch
>    wmic os get osarchitecture
>    ```
> 2. #### Download MongoDB for Windows.
>
>    Download the latest production release of MongoDB from the MongoDB downloads page. Ensure you download the correct version of MongoDB for
>      your Windows system. The 64-bit versions of MongoDB does not work with
>      32-bit Windows.
> 3. #### Install the downloaded file.
>
>    In Windows Explorer, locate the downloaded MongoDB msi file, which typically is located in the default Downloads folder. Double-click the
>      msi file. A set of screens will appear to guide you through the
>      installation process.
> 4. #### Move the MongoDB folder to another location (optional).
>
>    To move the MongoDB folder, you must issue the move command as an Administrator. For example, to move the folder to C:\mongodb:
>
>    Select <kbd>Start Menu</kbd> > <kbd>All Programs</kbd> > <kbd>Accessories</kbd>.
>
>    Right-click Command Prompt and select Run as Administrator from the popup menu.
>
>    Issue the following commands:
>
>    ```
>    cd \
>    move C:\mongodb-win32-* C:\mongodb
>    ```
>
>    MongoDB is self-contained and does not have any other system dependencies. You can run MongoDB from any folder you choose. You may
>      install MongoDB in any folder (e.g. `D:\test\mongodb`)
>
> ### Run MongoDB
>
> #### Warning:
>
> Do not make `mongod.exe` visible on public networks without running in
>   “Secure Mode” with the auth setting. MongoDB is designed to be run in
>   trusted environments, and the database does not enable “Secure Mode”
>   by default.
>
> 1. #### Set up the MongoDB environment.
>
>    MongoDB requires a data directory to store all data. MongoDB’s default data directory path is \data\db. Create this folder using the
>      following commands from a Command Prompt:
>
>    ```
>    md \data\db
>    ```
>
>    You can specify an alternate path for data files using the `--dbpath` option to `mongod.exe`, for example:
>
>    ```
>    C:\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe --dbpath d:\test\mongodb\data
>    ```
>
>    If your path includes spaces, enclose the entire path in double quotes, for example:
>
>    ```
>    C:\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe --dbpath "d:\test\mongo db data"
>    ```
> 2. #### Start MongoDB.
>
>    To start MongoDB, run `mongod.exe`. For example, from the Command Prompt:
>
>    ```
>    C:\Program Files\MongoDB\bin\mongod.exe
>    ```
>
>    This starts the main MongoDB database process. The waiting for connections message in the console output indicates that the
>      mongod.exe process is running successfully.
>
>    Depending on the security level of your system, Windows may pop up a Security Alert dialog box about blocking “some features” of
>      C:\Program Files\MongoDB\bin\mongod.exe from communicating on
>      networks. All users should select Private Networks, such as my home or
>      work network and click Allow access. For additional information on
>      security and MongoDB, please see the Security Documentation.
> 3. #### Connect to MongoDB.
>
>    To connect to MongoDB through the mongo.exe shell, open another Command Prompt. When connecting, specify the data directory if
>      necessary. This step provides several example connection commands.
>
>    If your MongoDB installation uses the default data directory, connect without specifying the data directory:
>
>    ```
>    C:\mongodb\bin\mongo.exe
>    ```
>
>    If you installation uses a different data directory, specify the directory when connecting, as in this example:
>
>    ```
>    C:\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe --dbpath d:\test\mongodb\data
>    ```
>
>    If your path includes spaces, enclose the entire path in double quotes. For example:
>
>    ```
>    C:\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe --dbpath "d:\test\mongo db data"
>    ```
>
>    If you want to develop applications using .NET, see the documentation of C# and MongoDB for more information.
> 4. #### Begin using MongoDB.
>
>    To begin using MongoDB, see Getting Started with MongoDB. Also consider the Production Notes document before deploying MongoDB in a
>      production environment.
>
>    Later, to stop MongoDB, press Control+C in the terminal where the mongod instance is running.
>
> ### Configure a Windows Service for MongoDB
>
> #### Note:
>
> There is a known issue for MongoDB 2.6.0, SERVER-13515, which prevents
>   the use of the instructions in this section. For MongoDB 2.6.0, use
>   Manually Create a Windows Service for MongoDB to create a Windows
>   Service for MongoDB instead.
>
> 1. #### Configure directories and files.
>
>    Create a configuration file and a directory path for MongoDB log output (logpath):
>
>    Create a specific directory for MongoDB log files:
>
>    ```
>    md "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\log"
>    ```
>
>    In the Command Prompt, create a configuration file for the logpath option for MongoDB:
>
>    ```
>    echo logpath=C:\Program Files\MongoDB\log\mongo.log > "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\mongod.cfg"
>    ```
> 2. #### Run the MongoDB service.
>
>    Run all of the following commands in Command Prompt with “Administrative Privileges:”
>
>    Install the MongoDB service. For `--install` to succeed, you must specify the logpath run-time option.
>
>    ```
>    "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\bin\mongod.exe" --config "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\mongod.cfg" --install
>    ```
>
>    Modify the path to the mongod.cfg file as needed.
>
>    To use an alternate dbpath, specify the path in the configuration file (e.g. C:\Program Files\MongoDB\mongod.cfg) or on the command line
>      with the --dbpath option.
>
>    If the dbpath directory does not exist, mongod.exe will not start. The default value for dbpath is `\data\db`.
>
>    If needed, you can install services for multiple instances of mongod.exe or mongos.exe. Install each service with a unique
>      `--serviceName` and `--serviceDisplayName`. Use multiple instances
>      only when sufficient system resources exist and your system design
>      requires it.
> 3. #### Stop or remove the MongoDB service as needed.
>
>    To stop the MongoDB service use the following command:
>
>    ```
>    net stop MongoDB
>    ```
>
>    To remove the MongoDB service use the following command:
>
>    ```
>    "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\bin\mongod.exe" --remove
>    ```
>
> ### Manually Create a Windows Service for MongoDB
>
> The following procedure assumes you have installed MongoDB using the
>   MSI installer, with the default path C:\Program Files\MongoDB 2.6
>   Standard.
>
> If you have installed in an alternative directory, you will need to
>   adjust the paths as appropriate.
>
> 1. #### Open an Administrator command prompt.
>
>    **Windows 7 / Vista / Server 2008 (and R2)**
>
>    Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, then type `cmd`, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
>
>    **Windows 8**
>
>    Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, then press <kbd>A</kbd>.
>
>    Execute the remaining steps from the Administrator command prompt.
> 2. #### Create directories.
>
>    Create directories for your database and log files:
>
>    ```
>    mkdir c:\data\db
>    mkdir c:\data\log
>    ```
> 3. #### Create a configuration file.
>
>    Create a configuration file. This file can include any of the configuration options for mongod, but must include a valid setting for
>      logpath:
>
>    The following creates a configuration file, specifying both the logpath and the dbpath settings in the configuration file:
>
>    ```
>    echo logpath=c:\data\log\mongod.log> "C:\Program Files\MongoDB 2.6 Standard\mongod.cfg"
>    echo dbpath=c:\data\db>> "C:\Program Files\MongoDB 2.6 Standard\mongod.cfg"
>    ```
> 4. #### Create the MongoDB service.
>
>    Create the MongoDB service.
>
>    ```
>    sc.exe create MongoDB binPath= "\"C:\Program Files\MongoDB 2.6 Standard\bin\mongod.exe\" --service --config=\"C:\Program Files\MongoDB 2.6 Standard\mongod.cfg\"" DisplayName= "MongoDB 2.6 Standard" start= "auto"
>    ```
>
>    `sc.exe` requires a space between “`=`” and the configuration values (eg “`binPath=`”), and a “” to escape double quotes.
>
>    If successfully created, the following log message will display:
>
>    ```
>    [SC] CreateService SUCCESS
>    ```
> 5. Start the MongoDB service.
>
>    ```
>    net start MongoDB
>    ```
> 6. #### Stop or remove the MongoDB service as needed.
>
>    To stop the MongoDB service, use the following command:
>
>    ```
>    net stop MongoDB
>    ```
>
>    To remove the MongoDB service, first stop the service and then run the following command:
>
>    ```
>    sc.exe delete MongoDB
>    ```

Comment: This documentation got me up an running after scratching my head. Some easy to follow steps: creating a data/db folder and starting the mongod service before trying to use mongo.exe.

Answer (score 16):

I realize you've already accepted an answer for this, but I wrote this short howto article to install mongodb into the `c:\wamp` directory and run it as a service.  Here is the gist of it.

Create these directories

```
mkdir c:\wamp\bin\mongodb\mongodb-win32...2.x.x\data
mkdir c:\wamp\bin\mongodb\mongodb-win32...2.x.x\data\db
mkdir c:\wamp\bin\mongodb\mongodb-win32...2.x.x\logs
mkdir c:\wamp\bin\mongodb\mongodb-win32...2.x.x\conf
```

Download and extract win32 binaries into c:\wamp directory along side mysql, apache.

[mongodb download page](http://www.mongodb.org/downloads)

Create a mongo.conf file

```
c:\wamp\bin\mongodb\mongodb-win32…2.x.x\conf\mongodb.conf

# mongodb.conf

# data lives here
dbpath=C:\wamp\bin\mongodb\mongodb-win32...2.x.x\data\db

# where to log
logpath=C:\wamp\bin\mongodb\mongodb-win32...2.x.x\logs\mongodb.log
logappend=true

# only run on localhost for development
bind_ip = 127.0.0.1                                                             

port = 27017
rest = true
```

Install as a service

```
mongod.exe --install --config c:\wamp\bin\mongodb\mongodb-win32...2.x.x\conf\mongodb.conf --logpath c:\wamp\bin\mongodb\mongodb-win32...2.x.x\logs\mongodb.log
```

Set service to automatic and start it using services.msc

Add path to mongo.exe to your path

Need more details? Read the full article here...

[Installing MongoDB on Windows the WAMP way](http://www.pronique.com/blog/installing-mongodb-on-windows-the-wamp-way)

Comment: I agree, but in this case the clean, semantic way is a bit involved.

Comment: It is a good practice to create a config file and use that config file to start the mongod process

Comment: Great answer! +1 but for those who got here via Google, it won't work in 3.

Answer (score 6):

**Step by Step Solution for windows 32 bit**

1. Download msi file for windows 32 bit.
2. Double click Install it, choose custom and browse the location where ever you have to install(personally i have create the mongodb folder in E drive and install it there).
3. Ok,now you have to create the data\db two folder where ever create
   it, i've created it in installed location root e.g on
   E:\
4. Now link the mongod to these folder for storing data use this
   command or modify according to your requirement go to using cmd
   `E:\mongodb\bin` and after that write in console 
   `mongod --dbpath E:\data` it will link.
5. Now navigate to E:\mongodb\bin and write mongod using cmd.
6. Open another cmd by right click and run as admin point to your
   monogodb installed directory  and then to bin just like
   E:\mongodb\bin and write this mongo.exe
7. Next - write `db.test.save({Field:'Hello mongodb'})` this command
   will insert the a field having name **Field** and its value **Hello
   mongodb**.
8. Next, check the record `db.test.find()` and press enter you will find
   the record that you have recently entered.

Answer (score 6):

**1. Download MongoDB**

**2. Install MongoDB**

**3. Create the required folders:**

```
"C:\MongoDB_2_6_Standard\bin\data\db"
"C:\MongoDB_2_6_Standard\logs"
"C:\MongoDB_2_6_Standard\etc"
```

NOTE: If the directories do not exist, mongod.exe will not start.

**4. Create a simple configuration file:**

```
systemLog:
    destination: file
    path: C:\MongoDB_2_6_Standard\logs\mongo.log
    logAppend: true
net:
    bindIp: 127.0.0.1
    port: 27017
```

More info about how to create a configuration file: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

**5. Install MongoDB as a Windows Service (this way it will start automatically when you reboot your computer)**

Run cmd with administrator privilegies, and enter the following commands:

```
"C:\MongoDB_2_6_Standard\bin\mongod.exe" --config "C:\MongoDB_2_6_Standard\etc\mongodb.conf" --dbpath c:\MongoDB_2_6_Standard\bin\data\db --directoryperdb --install
```

**6. Start the MongoDB Windows Service**

```
net start MongoDB
```

**7. Connect to MongoDB via shell/cmd for testing**

```
C:\MongoDB_2_6_Standard\bin\mongo.exe
```

NOTE: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/getting-started-with-the-mongo-shell/

**8. That's it! You are done. :)**

**9. Uninstall/remove the MongoDB Windows Service (if you messed up something)**

```
"C:\MongoDB_2_6_Standard\bin\mongod.exe" --remove
```

Answer (score 5):

Its very simple to install Mongo DB on windows 7 ( i used 32 bit win7 OS)

1. Install the correct version of Mongodb ( according to ur bit 32/64 .. imp :- 64 bit is not compatible with 32 bit and vice versa)

2.u can install Mongodb from thius website ( acc to ur OS) http://www.mongodb.org/downloads?_ga=1.79549524.1754732149.1410784175

3. DOWNLOAD THE .MSI OR zip file .. and install with proper privellages

4.copy the mongodb folder from c:programfiles  to d: [optional]

5.After installation open command prompt ( as administrator .. right click on cmd and u will find the option)

6. navigate to D:\MongoDB 2.6 Standard\bin
7. run mongo.exe  ... you might get this error  [image: you might get this error]
8. If you get then no isse you just need to do following steps

i)  try the coomand in following image yo will get to know the error 
[image]

ii)This means that u neeed to create a directory \data\db

iii) now you have two options either create above directory in c drive or create any "xyz" name directory somewhere else ( doesnot make and diffrence) .. lets create a directory of mongodata in d:

[image]

9. Now lets rerun the command but now like this  :-  mongod --dbpath d:\mongodata [shown in fig] 
   this time you will not get and error

[image]

10. Hope everything is fine till this point .. open new command propmt [sufficent privellages (admin)]

colured in orange will be the command u need to run .. it will open the new command propmt which we known as mongo shell (or mongodb shell)

[image]

11.dont close the shell[any of command promt as well] as in this we will create /delete/insert our databse operations

12. Lets perform basic operation

a) show databases 
b) show current databse 
c) creation of collection / inserting data into it (name will be  test)
d) show data of collection

12.please find scrren shot of results of our operation .. please not :- dont close any command propmt

[image]

13. a diffrent structure type of number is object id :- which is created automatically
14. Hope you get some important info for installing mongodb DB.

Answer (score 4):

Installing MongoDB on Windows is bit tricky compared to other Executable files.. Got a good reference after long search i got [Installing MongoDB in Windows](http://www.inmongodb.net/2015/05/installation-of-mongo-db-303-in-windows.html)

After Installing open command prompt and type "**mongod**", then keep the window minimized and open another command prompt window and type "**mongo**" and you will find the success message of connecting to the test database

Comment: page doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 4):

### Update Nov -2017

1) Go to Mongo DB download center https://www.mongodb.com/download-center#community and pick a flavor of MongoDB you want to install. You can pick from

- **MongoDB Atlas** -  MongoDB database in the cloud
- **Communiy Server** - MongoDb for windows (with and without SSL),iOS, Linux
- **OpManger**- Mongo Db for Data Center
- **Compass** - UI tool for MongoDB

To know your OS version run this command in cmd prompt

```
wmic os get caption
```

To know your CPU architecture(32 or 64 bit) run this command in cmd prompt

```
wmic os get osarchitecture
```

I am using Community version (150MBs- GNU license)

2) Click on MSI  and go through installation Process. Exe will install MongoDb and SSL required by the DB.

[image]

Mongo DB should be installed on your C drive

> C:\Program Files\MongoDB

MongoDB is self-contained, it means and does not have any other system dependencies. If you are low on disk in C drive then you can run MongoDB from any folder you choose.

You can now run mongodb.exe from bin folder. If you get Visual C++ error for missing dlls then download Visual C++ Redistributable from

https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=48145

After installation, try to rerun mongo.exe.

Comment: Thanks for your precise procedure @Hitesh

Answer (score 3):

You might want to check https://github.com/Thor1Khan/mongo.git
it uses a minimal workaround the 32 bit atomic operations on 64 bits operands
(could use assembly but it doesn't seem to be mandatory here)
Only digital bugs were harmed before committing

Answer (score 3):

1. Download .msi from   https://www.mongodb.com/download-center#community
2. Double click install  - complete option
3. Installation folder C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin
4. Create database folder in C://  -  c:/data/db  and  c:/data/log  and  c:/data/log/mongo.log   and set write permission if not
5. Open cmd prompt in Administrator mode , navigate to C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin
6. Type the following

   > > C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin>mongod --dbpath="c:/data/db" --logpath="c:/data/log/mongo.log"
7. Check folder c:/data/db   -  there should be many files and folder
8. Create a config file named "mongo.config" ** inside C:\data\
9. Type the following to set the config values from newly created config file

   > > C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin>mongod --config C:\data\mongo.config
10. Open another new cmd prompt in Administrator mode , navigate to C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin
    execute the following lines on the console.
11. Type the following to create service for MongoDB

    > > C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin>mongod --install --config C:\data\mongo.config --logpath="c:/data/log/mongo.log"

    If old MongoDB service exists then need to delete the old service first before mongod --install command, run the following in a new console to delete old mongodb service

    > > SC STOP MongoDB

    ```
    >> SC DELETE MongoDB
    ```
12. Type the following to start MongoDB

    > > C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin>net start MongoDB
13. Type the following to stop MongoDB

    > > C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin>net stop MongoDB

Now connect the DB on ip - 127.0.0.1 or 192.168.5.64  on port 27017 .

** File name - "mongo.config" ,  paste the following on config file -

bind_ip = 127.0.0.1,192.168.5.64

port = 27017

dbpath=C:\data\db

logpath=C:\data\log\mongo.log

Answer (score 3):

**Install MongoDB Community Edition for Windows.**

1.Now go to [Download Center](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center#community).

2. The Download Center should display the Current Stable Release for Windows
3. Click Download (msi) and run it
4. When you go through You can choose either the Complete or Custom setup type. Select Complete Setup.

**Starting MongoDB server from the Command Prompt**

1.Add this path to environmental variables

“C:\ProgramFiles\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin” For those who struggle to setup environmental variable please follow this steps

- Windows 10 and Windows 8
- In Search, search for and then select: System (Control Panel)
- Click the Advanced system settings link.
- Click Environment Variables. In the section System Variables, find
  the PATH environment variable and select it. Click Edit.
- If the PATH environment variable does not exist, click New.
- In the Edit System Variable (or New System Variable) window, specify
  the value of the PATH as
  “C:\ProgramFiles\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin”environment variable.
- Click OK.
- Close all remaining windows by clicking OK.
- Now create MongoDB Data Directory MongoDB requires a data directory to store all data. Open Command Prompt and paste below

> ```
> md "C:\data\db" "C:\data\log"
> ```

3.Lets point server to your database directory.Type below code

> ```
> mongod --dbpath="c:\data\db"
> ```

4.Now lets connect to MongoDB Type below code

> mongo

5.If it is working properly Command prompt will show

> [initandlisten] waiting for connections

Bingo!! You are done, Apparently it is bit confusing to use CLI, well MongoDB introduced a GUI which you can see the actual data ,

To use mongoDB GUI version Above steps must have been performed

1. Now go to Download Center. Download MongoDb Compass ,a GUI for MongoDB
2. Install it and open

You can see the hostname : localhost and port : 27017.

Whenever you wanted to connect to mongoDB Server , You have to open Command prompt

Type

> mongod

then again start a new Command prompt and type

> mongo

Keep ‘em all settings as it is in mongoDB Compass. Now click connect ,

You are in !! Easy .. isn’t it?

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: First download the .msi i.e is the installation file from

[Download MonggoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center?jmp=tutorials&_ga=2.233582811.411569310.1501444558-1958870715.1501444558#community)

Step 2: Perform the installation using the so downloaded .msi file.Automatically it gets stored in program files. You could perform a custom installation and change the directory.

After this, you should be able to see a MongoDB folder under program files

starting MongoDB shell and service is not big a deal I Got a good reference after the long search [Installing MongoDB in Windows](http://www.codeverb.com/get-started-with-mongodb-on-windows)

Answer (score 2):

1. Download from http://www.mongodb.org/downloads
2. Install .msi file in folder C:\mongodb
3. Create data, data\db, log directories and mongo.config file under C:\mongodb.
4. Add the following lines in
   "mongo.config" file dbpath=C:\mongodb\data\db\
   logpath=C:\mongodb\log\mongo.log
5. Start server : 
   mongod.exe --config="C:\mongodb\mongo.config"

That's it !!!

Answer (score 1):

WAMP = Windows + Apache + MySQL/MariaDB + PHP/Python/Perl

You can't use MongoDB in wamp.You need to install MongoDB separately