# MongoDB on a Windows 7 machine: No connection could be made

Tags: mongodb, initialization

After I have started Mongo using mongod.exe on a Windows 7  machine, I tried to start the mongo shell that failed with the error:

> Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:10061 No
>   connection could be made because the target machine actively refused
>   it.

...

> Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1),
>   connection attempt failed at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:146 exception:
>   connect failed

In the CMD where I running the mongod the output is:

> C:\Users\Vera>mongod --dbpath c:\mongodb\mongodata
>
> 2014-05-18T17:10:10.135-0300 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting :
>   pid=3296 port=27017 dbpath=c:\mongodb\mongodata 64-bit host=Vera-PC
>
> 2014-05-18T17:10:10.136-0300 [initandlisten] targetMinOS: Windows
>   7/Windows Server 2008 R2
>
> 2014-05-18T17:10:10.136-0300 [initandlisten] db version v2.6.1
>
> 2014-05-18T17:10:10.136-0300 [initandlisten] git version:
>   4b95b086d2374bdcfcdf2249272fb552c9c726e8
>
> 2014-05-18T17:10:10.136-0300 [initandlisten] build info: windows
>   sys.getwindowsversion(major=6, minor=1, build=7601, platform=2,
>   service_pack='Service Pack 1')
>
> BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
>
> 2014-05-18T17:10:10.136-0300 [initandlisten] allocator: system
>
> 2014-05-18T17:10:10.136-0300 [initandlisten] options: { storage: {
>   dbPath: "c:\mongodb\mongodata" } }
>
> 2014-05-18T17:10:10.242-0300 [initandlisten] journal
>   dir=c:\mongodb\mongodata\journal
>
> 2014-05-18T17:10:10.243-0300 [initandlisten] recover : no journal
>   files present, no recovery needed
>
> 2014-05-18T17:10:11.077-0300 [initandlisten] waiting for connections
>   on port 27017

Any suggestion how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What solved my issue was creating a file *startmongo.conf*  that sets the *bind_ip* to 127.0.0.1 . After that, I just created a **.bat* to start the mongo using something like:

`mongod --config c:\mongodb\bin\startmongo.conf`

More details could be seem at this  [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404742/how-to-install-mongodb-on-windows) .

Answer (score 42):

I got the same error and fixed it with:

1) `mkdir c:\data`

2) `cd data`

3) `mongod -dbpath .`

4) Now in another command window I was able to connect from my client using the `mongo` command.

Comment: Thanks , this worked form me as :  'mkdir c:\data'   ,   'mongod -dbpath c:\data'           Finally mongo in new cmd instance

Comment: For future users, there is a period after a space on #3 passing in the current path. Should be obvious, but still costed me a minute, could see someone getting hung up.

Comment: Suggestion to the mongodb team: create this default data directory for us upon installation.

Comment: it works for me, I can start mongo now but I lost the previous data. Anyone know how to retrieve back the old data?

Answer (score 25):

I got this problem. What fixed mine is:

1. Suppose you have a dir: `"C:\mongo_databse"`
2. Open Command Prompt and type (suppose you haved added the Mongo bin directory to PATH): `mongod --dbpath=C:/mongo_database`.
   There will be some log to the command prompt.
3. Now open **ANOTHER** command prompt then type in `mongo` then it works.

Answer (score 7):

1. I assume your mongo.config file to be located inside the mongodb folder in the same level to the bin directory.The contents of the mongo.config file are:

   ```
   dbpath=C:\mongodb\data
   logpath=C:\mongodb\log\mongo.log
   diaglog=3
   ```

   don't forget to create the data folder and log folder in the same level of bin directory  inside log folder  create the mongo.log empty file.
2. Point your command prompt to *C:\mongodb\bin* wherever  your mongo db bin folder is located.
3. create the mongo db service in windows  typing

   ```
   mongod.exe --storageEngine=mmapv1 --config=../mongo.config
   ```
4. from now unwards you can start the mongo db service as

   ```
   net start mongodb
   ```
5. finally you can connect to the mongo db server from the mongo db client  typing

   ```
   mongo.exe
   ```
6. once you  have gone successfully from step 1 to step 3 from the next time on wards you only need the step 4 and 5.to start the service and to connect.

Comment: step 3, needs to be appended with switch --install to install the service

Answer (score 3):

[it prompted me like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1xhu.png)

1)So, i created a path

`C:\data\db`

2)Now run

`mongod` in your terminal

it solved me issue!

Answer (score 2):

I got this error beacuse of not sufficient space in the disk.
Check your mongo log.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting a similar error when I was trying to start my mongo db via cmd. However the difference was I had a config file which has the path to the db and log folders and wanted to use the same. I was using mongo few days back and it was running fine but when I started using it again today it was giving me the error :

```
2015-05-27T10:33:22.820-0400 I CONTROL  Hotfix KB2731284 or later update is   installed, no need to zero-out data files
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.2
connecting to: test
2015-05-27T10:33:23.854-0400 W NETWORK  Failed to connect to 27.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:10061 No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
2015-05-27T10:33:23.857-0400 E QUERY    Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed at connect src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179:14) at (connect):1:6 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179 exception: connect failed
```

Here's how I fixed it :

1. Open cmd as admin and navigate to the bin folder of your MongoDB and type :           `mongod --config <path to your config file> --install`
2. Now start your mongo db service : `net start mongodb`
   you should get a message which says :  `The MongoDB service was started successfully.`
3. close this command prompt and open another one as admin, navigate to the bin folder once again and type `mongo`

This will connect you to the mongodb `test`.

Press ctrl+c anytime to exit.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

In Windows 10:
Executing below command restarts mongodb service (as administrator), required if there is a system restart after mongodb installation.

```
net start mongodb
```

Also make sure to check, if there is a MongoDBInstallation folder/data and /data/db folder created, same can be obtained at MongoDBInstallation\bin\mongod.cfg

```
mongod --dbpath=c:\MongoDBInstallation\data\db
```

Answer (score 1):

Open task manager, click on the services tabs on the top. From the list right click on mongoDB then click start.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar experience to @user1501382, but tweaked everything slightly in accordance with [the documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/)

1) `cd c:` //changes to C drive

2) `mkdir data` //creates directory data

3) `cd data`

4) `mkdir db` //creates directory db

5) `cd db` //changes directory so that you are in `c:/data/db`

6) run `mongod -dbpath`

7) close this terminal, open a new one and run `mongod`

Answer (score 0):

for mongodb 3.0 versions use "--smallfiles".

e.g:-

mongod --dbpath="C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.0" --logpath="C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.0\data\log.txt" --smallfiles --install

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is a better way to run it.
For me, I use these settings to create a directory and to a determinate new path for the MongoDB.
The important thing for me is that I miss to **run** it as a server (`mongod`) and after that into ***another*** terminal I type `mongo` which provide me an option to use the database.
I hope this could help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer on this page. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mongo-app?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio
So, first, make a folder for your data; then, open one command shell

```
mongod --dbpath <data_directory_path>
```

then, open another shell, do whatever you want to do. You can see in MongoDB Compass, there are collections if you had one before.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the [above answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26204574/8898138)
, and it worked, but had a very important problem: My previous collections were lost in another mongoDB data folder which I didn't know where they are and how to get them back.

Before I run in to this `mongo` error, I was running `mongo` with no problem. When my windows10 boot files got corrupted and My computer went into blue screen, `mongo` ran into this error. So I just tried to retrieve the previous condition which I just was running mongo in one terminal and not `mongod` in another, so

I repaired `mongoDB` with it's installation `exe` file, and now everything is ok.

This is my `mongoDB` specs: **mongodb-win32-x86_64-2012plus-4.2.1**

Hope this help you too.

Answer (score 0):

Just type `mongod` in one command prompt and then run `mongo` in another.

Answer (score 0):

Simply follow the following steps mostly your problem will be solved(Windows 10)
services->mongodb->change auto to run

Answer (score 0):

you can go to services>>Mongo DB server .. right click and press start . This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

By simple step ,I was resolve this problem
first step - make a New folder in C-drive in PC with name - "data"
second step- now open this "data" folder
Third step - Inside  the "data" folder, again make a new "db" folder
Note - Just leave it this both folder empty, no need to add any content inside this,
and run "mongo" and "mongod" in PowerShell of your PC.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, and this is how I resolved it,

follow the below steps:-

1. Open **mongod.cfg** file
2. Add the **bindIpAll: true** tag in the
   net (Network Interfaces) section
3. restart the mongoDB services.

   ```
   # network interfaces
   net:
     port: 27017
     bindIpAll: true
     #bindIp: 127.0.0.1
   ```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, MongoDB windows service has been stopped. just check whether the service is in Running status

[image]

Hope this helps