# mongo db cannot start

Tags: mongodb, database

After calling command mongodb.exe the error message says:

> Could not connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:10061 No connection can be made because the target machine actively refused it.
>   Blockquote

I wonder how to deal with this.

Comment: `mongo.exe` is the shell which is used to connect to a running mongodb instance to send commands to it. Do you have one running? (`mongod.exe`)

Comment: I am trying to run mongo in order to connect it with python..M just beginner and I cant figure out how to do it.

Comment: You need to run `mongod.exe`, not `mongo.exe`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add configuration path like this:

To start the server :

`C:\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe --dbpath "path_to_directory_to store_data`"

And to connect to Mongo:

```
C:\mongodb\bin\mongo.exe
```

If this doesnt work try  apply this method:

or try this:

[MongoDB on a Windows 7 machine: No connection could be made](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23726684/mongodb-on-a-windows-7-machine-no-connection-could-be-made)

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting suggests you are running the shell (`mongo.exe`) rather than the database (`mongod.exe`).  The shell will, by default, attempt to connect to the database - in other words it will essentially do what you state you wish to do with python.

You can either run the `mongod.exe` manually with appropriate options, or you can install it as a service.  In either case, there are detailed instructions on how to do this here:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/