# MongoDB - No Connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: mongodb

I tried start mongod.exe but it wouldn't open.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB on a Windows 7 machine: No connection could be made](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23726684/mongodb-on-a-windows-7-machine-no-connection-could-be-made)

Comment: @sss nope, different solution

Comment: ohh really..see http://stackoverflow.com/a/28593287/5735460

Comment: I'm having the same problem but connection to remove windows server

Answer (score 2):

the problem was that there was no "db" folder in my data folder. I just added the folder and now it's fully operational.

Answer (score 0):

```
mongod --dbpath "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\data"
```

As per the error message I tried it and this code worked. Make sure you start command prompt in Administrator mode.