# How to connect to MongoDB in Windows 7

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to get MongoDB installed and running on my new Windows 7 computer. However, I cannot seem to be able to connect to MongoDB when using the mongo shell.

MongoDB shell version v4.0.0
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2018-07-31T16:33:22.968+0530 E QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:251:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed

Comment: Make sure  Mongo DB running on your machine,Run mongod command before running mongo shell and also you may have to create data directory for MongoBb to store collection data

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23726684/mongodb-on-a-windows-7-machine-no-connection-could-be-made