# No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. error

Tags: javascript, mongodb, command, connection, prompt

No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
when I am connecting to a mongodb server locally it's just showing a error you have seen above any body know the solution

Comment: does this answer solves your problem  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23726684/mongodb-on-a-windows-7-machine-no-connection-could-be-made)

Comment: That error means there is nothing listening on the port you are trying to connect to.  Make sure the mongod is running, and make sure you are connecting to the port it is listening on.