# MongoDB plugin for IntelliJ - Timed out while waiting to connect after xxxx ms

Tags: mongodb, intellij-idea

I'm trying to follow [this](http://thinktostart.wordpress.com/2013/10/22/build-your-own-twitter-archive-and-analyzing-infrastructure-with-mongodb-java-and-r-part-1/) guide but I'm stuck to the point where I have to test the MongoDB plugin. I have installed MongoDB in my system and the Mongo Plugin to IntelliJ. In the MongoDB plugin settings the "Path to Mongo Executable" is correct (it shows the success symbol when I test it).

[image]

But when I try to add a Mongo Server the Test Connection fails. The error is: "Timed out while waiting to connect after xxxx ms". I tried starting mongod.exe manually, restarting IntelliJ and reboot. Nothing works. What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The answer is given by Shivam Srivastava in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404742/how-to-install-mongodb-on-windows) thread. **The problem was that I hadn't set the dbpath**. Shivam shows step by step how to achieve this.

Comment: Ah, I see. So your problem seems to be that `mongod` was not starting correctly.

Comment: I still have the problem, even after creating the dbpath directories and setting the dbpath...

Comment: Hello Sofia, it's been 2 years since I made this post and I haven't used MongoDB since then, so I have no clue on how to help you. Maybe you should try your luck creating a new post.

Answer (score 2):

I just downloaded it and played around with the plugin. I got it to connect only after starting up `mongod` manually beforehand. I don't even know if you can start up the `mongod` process from IntelliJ, as after reading the [documentation](https://github.com/dboissier/mongo4idea), there is nothing about starting up the server. So basically I followed the steps you outlined, but before hitting "Test Connection", I start up the server manually. Once that is done, I was able to use the plugin's functionality.

Comment: It's the same. I don't understand what's wrong. I even tried downloading the 32bit version of MongoDB (I'm on Windows 8.1 64 bit). When I open mongod.exe a console window appears which closes immediately after. Is this normal? Should the console windows stay open?

Comment: @Aventinus_, so you were not able to run `mongod` without IntelliJ? You should be able to run `mongod` from the command line and connect to it by running `mongo`. Also, if you have Windows 64-bit, then you should run the 64-bit version of MongoDB.

Comment: I am using OS X and get the same problem.  I can use the command line utility (the same one I specify in 'Path to Mongo Shell' (i.e. /usr/local/bin/mongo) and connections/queries working fine.    What is so odd with intelliJ plugin?