# How can I install MongoDB 3.X on Windows without admin rights?

Tags: mongodb

I'm on a Windows 7 (64-bit) box and do not have admin rights.

It appears from the MongoDB download page (see http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/) that the latest version only an MSI install is available (no zip version).

I tried running the 3.0.4 MSI.  I clicked custom so I could change the directory to install to.  I used %USERPROFILE%\MyProgs\MongoDB-3.0.4, so no admin rights would be needed.  It ran for a bit but then prompted me to enter admin credentials.  I hit escape (like clicking on X at top right) to close the window.  On other MSI installs this has worked.  I tried it again and clicked "No" but in both cases received the message

```
MongoDB 3.0.4 2008R2Plus SSL (64 bit) setup was interrupted.
Your system has not been modified. [...]
```

This article does a GREAT job going through how to install MongoDB on Windows:
[How to install mongoDB on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404742/how-to-install-mongodb-on-windows)

My observation is that v2.4.14 is the last version that is available via the ZIP format.  So for now, I'm using that version.

**Is there any other way to install the MongoDB version 3.X MSI without admin rights?**

NOTE: On the MongoDB Download page https://www.mongodb.org/downloads there is a link titled *View Build Archive* (it sends you here https://www.mongodb.org/dl/win32/x86_64-2008plus-ssl, and that site lists *.zip formatted files).  I thought I had found my own solution to the question, but when I unzipped the files, and added the "bin" to my path and ran the programs (mongo, and mongod) I received an Windows Dialog that says:

```
mongod.exe - System Error
The program can't start because LIBEAY32.dll is missing from your
computer.  Try reinstalling the program to fix the problem
```

I stopped here and posted this question.  Thanks for any help.

**For now I'm using the version that supported the zip format (v2.4.14) and that version does work**.

NOTE2: The v2.4.14 zip formatted install doesn't have a file named LIBEAY32.dll), or I might have tried using that file with the newer version.

Comment: You should definitely accept [Erick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36879172/1426227).

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to install the latest MSI (including the one with SSL) without admin rights via command line.

```
msiexec /a mongodb-win32-x64-3.2.5.msi /qb TARGETDIR="C:\MongoDB"
```

This will copy the binaries into `C:\MongoDB\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin`

I dislike long paths like that, so I create a symlink inside the folder:

```
cd C:\MongoDB
mklink /j bin C:\MongoDB\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin
```

That will create a soft link as `C:\MongoDB\bin` (which you can add to your `PATH` environment variable).

```
mongo --version
mongod --version
```

Both should return version 3.2.5.

You can do this with most packages, we have to do similar with Python 2.7 and Node 4.4.3 MSI packages on work computers that do not have admin rights.

Comment: @ Cassio Mazzochi Molin, Sorry for not accepting sooner.

Comment: Thanks... just curious, Why /a? that means 'adminstrative' ... I tried without it which gave me a popup of 'msiexe' manual, ultimately I installed using '/a'. I guess you must use /a but only on folders on which you full control/access.

Comment: isn't /a - administrative install ? https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/msiexec.html

Answer (score 5):

You can download the "legacy" version which is the unsigned non msi version as a zip.  The disclaimer is listed as

> The 64-bit legacy build does not include SSL encryption and lacks
>   newer features of Windows that enhance performance. Use this build for
>   Windows Server 2003, 2008, or Windows Vista

The 3.0.5 version is https://fastdl.mongodb.org/win32/mongodb-win32-x86_64-3.0.5.zip

Answer (score 4):

The latest version is available as zip download.

[https://www.mongodb.com/dr/fastdl.mongodb.org/win32/mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-ssl-4.0.6.zip/download][1]

- Download and Unzip into folder where user has permissions e.g c:\users\xxx\mongodb.
- Enter the path to bin folder (e..g c:\users\xxx\mongodb\bin) into the
  environment variable 'PATH'. To access path variable press Win + R
  and then enter rundll32 sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables.
- Select Path and click edit. Then enter new and there enter the path
  to bin folder. Click OK and OK to save and exit.
- Check Mongo version from command line using command mongo --version.

Note: Don't forget to create db folder in C drive that is required for mongo to work locally. All set.