# MongoDB Connect Fail Error in windows

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql, connect

I have installed MongoDB shell version v3.4.9 in windows 7 and when I type mongo in cmd then I get the following error

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2j1na.png) see the screenshot

Please tell me how to resolve it.

I am a beginner in MongoDB.

Comment: Did you run `mongod`?

Comment: yes but still i get the same error

Comment: You need to give more details. Is the server even running? Because it doesn't look like it. What does `netstat` output look like? Are you running a firewall? Are you sure `mongod` shows up in your process list?

Answer (score 0):

Run a `netstat -an` from a Console window. Then locate the default MongoDB port 27017 in the output. If it's there you may have a firewall issue.

If it isn't then MongoDB is not running or not listening on the default port. In this case you want to either start the windows service if you've installed MonggDB as a service or manually run `mongod`. The following links provide some guidance around that:

[How to install mongoDB on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404742/how-to-install-mongodb-on-windows)

[How do I start Mongo DB from Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20796714/how-do-i-start-mongo-db-from-windows)

Comment: the default MongoDB port 27017 is not in the output now what to do. I tried reinstalling it but same error