# Cannot install nor cancel mongodb installation

Tags: mongodb

I've tried running the setup with and without selecting 'install mongo compass' option, but still I'm neither able to install it nor cancel the installation.
This setup dialogue then freezes without any progress for more than 20-30mins. This is literally just what happens after downloading the setup from their website(https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/community?tck=docs_server) in msi format and starting the install. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.
I've selected "complete" setup type then "Install MongoD as a Service MongoDB as a service" and
"Run the service as Network Service user (Default)"

[image]

Comment: Did you run setup as administrator? Maybe disable "Install MongoD as a Service MongoDB as a service" - you can install the service also manually by running, `mongod --install` see [mongod.exe](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod.exe/)

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I did a run as admin and disabled "Install MongoD as a Service MongoDB as a service" as per your suggestion, but unfortunately, it's still the same for the past 15mins.

Comment: What is your Windows version? Did you install it before already? Perhaps the service is running already and installer fails to stop the existing one.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I have windows 10, and no, I've never used nor installed mongodb before. (mongo --version =>mongo not recognised)

Comment: Did you try to install Mongo Compass? Otherwise, try the zip download. You can install the service as above and you only have to create data and log directory.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I tried following instructions in [Mongo Installation Process in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404742/how-to-install-mongodb-on-windows) and unsurprisingly, I cannot even set --dbpath. I get these:

Comment: ```{"t":{"$date":"2021-05-01T23:46:07.530+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-05-01T23:46:07.536+05:30"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-05-01T23:46:07.537+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648602, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen in use."}```

Comment: My system variables are set to `c:..\bin

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231828/discussion-between-virtualpanda-and-wernfried-domscheit).

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue, and it was due to my antivirus software. I turned off both the antivirus and Windows Defender, and that resolved the problem.