# MongoDB .msi installer is not responding

Tags: mongodb

I have downloaded the `.msi` multiple times and tried to run it in a variety of ways. However, I cannot install MongoDB on my Windows 10 machine.

When I click the `.msi`, I get the first "preparing to install" pop-up, and then it just goes away. Nothing happens.

Also, shows that the installer is not responding!

Any solutions? Thank you.

Comment: Maybe see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67339843/cannot-install-nor-cancel-mongodb-installation - did you run the setup as Admin?